# How to redeploy metrics-server

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, docker-for-mac

I have a Kubernetes cluster running on my local machine(via docker-for-desktop) and a metrics-server has been deployed to monitor CPU Usage. I want to make some changes in the `metrics-server-deployment.yaml` file which resides in `/metrics-server/deploy/1.8+`

I am done with the changes but I can't figure how to redeploy the metrics-server so that it will reflect the new changes. I am new to K8S and would love to get some help/tips or useful resources.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From the directory where you have `metrics-server-deployment.yaml`, just run:

```
kubectl apply -f metrics-server-deployment.yaml
```

If it complains, you can also manually delete it and run:

```
kubectl create -f metrics-server-deployment.yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

You can manually edit the file(s) and then use

```
kubectl delete -f /metrics-server/deploy/1.8+
kubectl apply -f /metrics-server/deploy/1.8+
```

or (in my opinion the nicer version) you can just edit the deployment itself with

```
kubectl edit deployment -n kube-system metrics-server
```